# Python Watchdog - src_path inconsistent

Tags: python, python-2.7, watchdog

I'm trying to write a script that watches a specific log file for modification, but I can't get it to see any .txt files. It works fine with other types of files.

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from os.path import expanduser

file_to_watch = 'test.txt'

class FileModifiedHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def __init__(self, path, file_name, callback):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.callback = callback

        self.observer = Observer()
        self.observer.schedule(self, path, recursive=False)
        self.observer.start()
        self.observer.join()

    def on_modified(self, event): 

        print "Event: %s" % (event)
        print "Ends with %s: %s" % (self.file_name, event.src_path.endswith(self.file_name))

        if not event.is_directory and event.src_path.endswith(self.file_name):
            self.callback()

if __name__ == '__main__':


    def callback():
        print("FILE WAS MODIFIED")

    FileModifiedHandler('.', file_to_watch, callback)
```

When I set file_to_watch to a .py file, the log returns the correct source path, but when I change it to a .txt file in the same folder, it stops at the directory. I'm not sure what the reason for this is. Here is what the program returns:

```
Event: <FileModifiedEvent: src_path='/Users/nick/Documents/Python/WatchdogTest.py'>
Ends with WatchdogTest.py: True
FILE WAS MODIFIED

Event: <DirModifiedEvent: src_path='/Users/nick/Documents/Python'>
Ends with test.txt: False
```

Answer (score 0):

can you rename file `test.txt` to some other name say `mytest.txt` I feel like /t is treated differently or may be you can add escape sequence to bypass.

Comment: I solved the issue. I was testing the code by changing in TextEdit (on Mac), but when I modified in a different text editor (I used Brackets) it started to work. Maybe TextEdit saves a new file instead of modifying the existing one?

Comment: Many editors write the changes to a new file, and/or write a backup file, and swap the new and old files. Using shell commands like mv, cp, touch, is a much more reliable way to test the watchdog vs testing the editor. see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35448575/54745