# Updates to text file are not being parsed using python

Tags: python, parsing, text

I'm parsing data from a text file ('placlog.txt') that is continuously being updated. As I run the code everything prints as expected, but if there are any updates to the placlog file while the code is running it is not printed.

The placlog file is being updated by a third-party program and I am using the above code to read the file and print any updates.

Once formatted, the text should be sent via a Telegram API. This part is also working initially.

```
import urllib.parse
import time
import requests
import os


def post_to_telegram(msg):
    #print(msg)
    base_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot&text="{}'.format(msg)
    requests.get(base_url)

def check_url_inMsgList(stringToMatch, msgList):
    for i in msgList:
        if (stringToMatch in i):
            return False
    return True


try:
    f = open("oldFile.txt", "r")
    msgList = f.read().split("\n")
    f.close()
except:
    f = open("oldFile.txt", "w")
    msgList = []
    f.close()
selections = []
urr = ""
name = ""
pie = ""
ourLines = 2400
url_found = 0
name_found = 0
pie_found = 0
while (True):
    file1 = open('placlog.txt', 'r')
    Lines = file1.readlines()
    file1.close()
    while (True):
        # print("-------------------------------")
        if (ourLines == len(Lines)):
            break
        elif (ourLines > len(Lines)):
            ourLines = 0
        else:
            txt = Lines[ourLines].strip()
            tlist = txt.split("&")
            ourLines = ourLines + 1
            for subtxt in tlist:
                if "eventurl=" in subtxt:
                    a = subtxt[9:len(subtxt) - 3]
                    url = "www.awebsite.com/%23" + a.replace("%23", "/")
                    #url = url.replace("%23", "#")
                    for i in range(10):
                        if "F" + str(i) + "/" in url:
                            url = url.split("F" + str(i) + "/")[0] + "F" + str(i) + "/"
                    urr = url
                    url_found = 1
                elif "bit=" in subtxt:
                    name = urllib.parse.unquote(subtxt[4:len(subtxt)])
                    name_found = 1
                elif "pie\":" in subtxt:
                    a = subtxt.split("price")[1]
                    pie = a.split("\"")[2]
                    pie = float(pie)
                    pie = round(pie, 1)
                    pie = str(pie)
                    pie_found = 1
                    selections.append(url + name + pie)
                    msg = (url + " " + name + " " + pie)
                    stringToFind = url + " " + name
                    if (check_url_inMsgList(stringToFind, msgList)):
                        post_to_telegram(msg)
                        msgList.append(msg)
                        print(msg)
                        f = open("oldFile.txt", "a+")
                        f.write(msg + "\n")
                        f.close()
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                elif "minodds=" in subtxt:
                    a = subtxt.split("minodds=")[1]
                    pie = a.split("&")[0]
                    pie = float(pie)
                    rie = round(pie, 1)
                    pie = str(pie)
                    pie_found = 1
                    selections.append(url + name + pie)
                    msg = (url + " " + name + " " + pie)
                    stringToFind = url + " " + name
                    if (check_url_inMsgList(stringToFind, msgList)):
                        post_to_telegram(msg)
                        msgList.append(msg)
                        print(msg)
                        f = open("oldFile.txt", "a+")
                        f.write(msg + "\n")
                        f.close()
                    time.sleep(0.5)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You only open the file `placlog.txt` once for reading, read all its lines, then close it right after. You never open that file again at all, let alone in write mode, so why do you expect anything in it to be changing?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using watchdog, and seeing if that helps your situation. It can monitor for file system changes, so you could define a function which is executed when the placlog.txt file is changed/updated.

A good guide can be found here: http://thepythoncorner.com/dev/how-to-create-a-watchdog-in-python-to-look-for-filesystem-changes/

From that guide, you can simply change the functions defined to suit your needs i.e.

```
def on_modified(event):
    if event.src_path == "path/to/placlog.txt":
        with open('placlog.txt', 'r') as placlog:
            lines = file1.readlines()
```

Could you try this out and see if it helps? I still recommend the with statement for file i/o since you always want your file to close no matter what.

This link might also be useful since they are also monitoring a single .txt file: [Python Watchdog - src_path inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125974/python-watchdog-src-path-inconsistent)

watchdog documentation: https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/

Note: Deleted the old answer since you clarified the question.

Comment: With this solution you'll have to restructure some of your code. Most of it can go under that on_modified function, as it is what you want to happen when that file is changed, but as for the rest, you can follow that guide to set up an observer inside a while loop (which means you can get rid of your while loops). The observer will then call the on_modified function (where you will have your code) when the placlog.txt file is modified.