# How to print the correct filename when modifying a filesystem?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code, I am monitoring the filesystem. Whenever I modify a file, `event.src_path` does not show the name of the file. Instead, it shows `.goutputstream-CL5N00`. I don't know what is wrong?

**Given result**

```
event type: modified path : /home/bilal/Videos/folder1/fd/.goutputstream-CL5N00
```

**Expected result**

```
event type: modified path : /home/bilal/Videos/folder1/fd/touch
```

**Code**

```
import os
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def on_modified(self, event):
        print(f'event type: {event.event_type} path : {event.src_path}')

def monitor_folders(path):
    event_handler = MyHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()

folder1 = '/home/bilal/Videos/folder1'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m1 = monitor_folders(folder1)
    m1.start()
    m1.join()
```

Comment: Need a bit more code. Is this program using `from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler`? Once the program is running how do you trigger the event?

Comment: @JasonHarrison Yes I am using `from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler`

Comment: How do you trigger the event? Would executing `touch /home/bilalVideos/folder1/test.txt` in a shell be an expected test?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough information in your question about what is changing the files under the path that you specify. It could be a text editor, many of which write backup files, write to a new file, perform file swaps, etc. It could be some other program that creates or moved files (which your code would not detect).

Using shell commands like mv, cp, touch, is a much more reliable way to test the watchdog vs testing the editor. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35448575/54745) where the behaviour of vim is described.

You asked this question also on [reddit/r/learnpython](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/mbjb2c/how_to_print_the_correct_filename_when_modifying/) and [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5298014/answer) and revealed that you were using "the default Linux text editor" which appears to create backup files, and when you tried SublimeText everything worked as expected, probably because SublimeText uses some other directory for backups. VSCode with the pytest module uses files under ./pytest_cache

In additional to providing more information, you could have used more information from the system. The watchdog package has a FileSystemEventHandler has an on_any_event function:

```
class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

@staticmethod
def on_any_event(event):
    desc = ""
    if event.is_directory:
        desc += "Directory "
    else:
        desc += "File "

    if event.event_type == "moved":
        desc += f"moved {event.src_path}"
    elif event.event_type == "deleted":
        desc += f"deleted {event.src_path}"
    elif event.event_type == "created":
        desc += f" created {event.src_path}"
    elif event.event_type == "modified":
        desc += f"modified {event.src_path}"
    elif event.event_type == "closed":
        desc += f"closed {event.src_path}"
    else:
        desc = f"UNEXPECTD {desc} {event.event_type} {event.src_path}"

    print(desc)
```

Sometimes by limiting yourself to just only type of events (modified) you miss the other events that might be telling you are using the wrong tool to test the system.